# Choosing font size for a web form

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

I am building some Web forms with ms-access. For the most part the fidelity of the form inside of ms-access and the same form when published to the web and run from a web browser looks very good.

However I the problem is with some list boxes. Here is a screen shot of the client form.

[image]

And, then the same form when published to Access Web services.

[image]

The form when run in a browser looks better sized then in the access client. The font I am using for the 4 list boxes (time picker)  is "MS Sans Serif", point size 8.

As the two screen shots show, the 2 form in a web browser looks quite different.   I sized the list boxes larger then needed in the client side to get the good looking results in the web browser.

I would rather size the form in the client to much like this screen shot:

[image]

It certainly possible that I might have to live with this size and rendering difference. I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions in regards to picking a different font that might improve this situation? I included the SharePoint tag in this question since Access Web services does run on SharePoint. Perhaps there is some Web Server settings I don't know about that might improve this situation?

I tried about 10 different of the most common fonts (Calibri, Arial, Times New Roman etc.) and the sizing issue did not really improve much.

I am new to the web world so issues like what font to choose or what a long time web developer would choose in this case is much breaking new ground for me.

Is there a particular font (and size) that would be a better choice for those 4 list boxes? Or am I wasting my time looking at fonts and hould e looking else where such as anchoring of controls etc.?

Comment: Quick thought: I'd redesign that form and use combo boxes instead of lists.

Comment: Albert, you should get away from using bitmapped screen fonts in your Access client apps, and MS Sans Serif is one of them. You don't mention Tahoma as one of the fonts you've tried, but that's the one that I think works best (though I've started using the Office 2007 set of fonts lately, of which Calibri is the choice here).

Comment: All that said, I would not really worry that much about things looking different between the browser and Access. For heaven's sake, you'll likely see more variation between web browsers and Windows version than you will between Access an any single web browser. Worrying about pixel-perfect rendering in a browser-based application is a recipe for frustration as the platform is not designed for that and never can work that way. It's a goal that you shouldn't have in the first place.

Comment: Great point about being flexible here and looking for 100% pixel perfect (silly for any web stuff). Strange thing here is that during beta 1, beta 2, RC (release candidate), I never experienced this problem.  Over a long period this was fine and now retail versions display scroll bars on the Web side if I don't size those boxes quite a bit larger then needed on client side. I like the Calibri font (good suggestion BTW). I thought I would ask in case of some traditional Web font I missing that would help me solve this problem which as you mention is really is not the end of the world anyway.

Comment: As for the other suggestion to use combo boxes in place of list box? With combo box you have drop the box down FIRST and THEN slide to select a number. That quite a bit more work and dexterity required on the users part. The above is a SINGLE touch or click on the screen (especially on my iPad). So the above works VERY well with touch screens. With above I can change both hours say to 4 pm and 5:30 pm with just TWO mouse clicks. It real fast and easy. I do have the screen real estate to burn up here. If I did not have the screen Real estate then sure a combo box would be my choice.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a font issue, but a styling issue. Unfortunately, if you are new to the web, you have managed to get dropped into a rather complicated corner of. With Access publishing web pages hosted in SharePoint, it is about as complicated as it gets CSS/HTML styling wise.

So, debugging what is going on is pretty hard without access to the particular html and css used to render this page. Even then there is no guarantee that there is going to be an easy solution.

Your first port of call should be installing the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar, this will allow you to inspect the html rendered on that part of the page and attempt to change the styling applied to different tags.

While learning this stuff is not going to be a waste of time, it will take a huge amount of time to get the hang of.

Over all I would recommend just living with it until you have some CSS knowledge available to help out.